# How to set runtime mapping on Elasticsearch 6.8

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a data point with a mapping set as long but I want to change it to double. In Elasticsearch the value is stored in double when I retrieve the value it gives an integer part of the value.

Answer (score 0):

1. Once the mapping for a field is created, you cannot change the data type any more.
2. Why do you think Elasticsearch stores a long as double? That is not the case — see the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/number.html) (that would make storage requirements worse).
3. "runtime" in the title confused me for a bit. We introduced a concept called [runtime](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/runtime.html) in the more recent 7.x versions that could also be used to solve your problem. But it's not available in 6.8